# I Cannot Load the Three.js Library In Cloud 9

Tags: javascript, cloud9-ide

I am trying to make a three-d js game in c9. This is my html:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Tower Defender</title></head>
  <body>
    <script src="/three.js"></script>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the `main.js` file:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth  / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.1;
}
render();
```

Both of these files are in the main dir of the project. I have the `three.js` file also in the main dir. The `three.js` file is the file that is in the `src` dir in the three.js download folder. (The dowload file is called `Three.js`, and I renamed it with all lowercase in c9). When I run `main.html` and open the webpage, nothing is there. I check the js console, and i see this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: THREE.Scene is not a constructor                      main.js:5
```

I also see little warning signs on the left side of the code window, where ever the code uses `THREE`. To me, it looks like everything should be working fine.

EDIT:

I have changed the html to this:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Tower Defender</title></head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although this looks alright as per the Three.js docs page, you should add the javascript console log output. It will elaborate what the problem is here.

Comment: i did: `Uncaught TypeError: THREE.Scene is not a constructor                      main.js:5`

Comment: Try `console.log`ing both `THREE` and `THREE.Scene` at the beginning of your file. When you mouse over the warnings, what does it say the problem is?

Comment: now i am so confused. `console.log(THREE)` got this: `Object {REVISION: "78", MOUSE: Object, CullFaceNone: 0, CullFaceBack: 1, CullFaceFront: 2…}`

Comment: just to clarify. If you type in `new THREE.Scene();` within the console, what happens?

Comment: i get this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined(…)`

Comment: wait oops i have another bug now. never mind

Comment: i fixed the other bug, and now i get this when i type `new THREE.Scene();`: `Uncaught TypeError: THREE.Scene is not a constructor(…)`

Comment: actually, try to have it set up like this: http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene

Comment: but i don't want inline js, it looks terible. or at least i think so. if i do that though, it works fine, i just REALLY want to avoid that